# How to create filter's UI in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, grid, filter

I want to create something like this in my custom module on admin panel:

[image]

Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are asking how to create the magento admin gird. here is the [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/) to create magento admin grid and all the **filters** are part of **grid**

**Step 1.**

Create new module in etc/modules called Inchoo_Orders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Orders>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Inchoo_Orders>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2.**

Next thing we’ll do is create folder Inchoo/Orders inside app/code/community and inside we’ll make few folders: Block, controllers, etc, Helper.

**inchoo_orders**

**Step 3.**

Create config.xml inside etc folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Orders>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </Inchoo_Orders>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <inchoo_orders>
                <class>Inchoo_Orders_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>inchoo_orders_resource</resourceModel>
            </inchoo_orders>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <inchoo_orders_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Inchoo_Orders</module>
                </setup>
            </inchoo_orders_setup>
        </resources>

        <blocks>
            <inchoo_orders>
                <class>Inchoo_Orders_Block</class>
            </inchoo_orders>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <inchoo_orders>
                <class>Inchoo_Orders_Helper</class>
            </inchoo_orders>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <inchoo_orders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Inchoo_Orders_Adminhtml</inchoo_orders>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**Step 4**

Create adminhtml.xml file inside etc folder which will add a link to our orders page in magento admin panel.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <inchoo_orders translate="title" module="inchoo_orders">
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <title>Orders - Inchoo</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/order/</action>
                </inchoo_orders>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Step 5**

Create blank helper class.

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Orders_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**Step 6**

Next step is to create controller for our grid.

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Orders_Adminhtml_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Orders Inchoo'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('sales/sales');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_orders/adminhtml_sales_order'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_orders/adminhtml_sales_order_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }

    public function exportInchooCsvAction()
    {
        $fileName = 'orders_inchoo.csv';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_orders/adminhtml_sales_order_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
    }

    public function exportInchooExcelAction()
    {
        $fileName = 'orders_inchoo.xml';
        $grid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_orders/adminhtml_sales_order_grid');
        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
    }
}
```

**Step 7**

Next thing we do is create grid container in Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order.php

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Orders_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'inchoo_orders';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sales_order';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('inchoo_orders')->__('Orders - Inchoo');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

**Step 8**

Last step is making grid class in Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Inchoo_Orders_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('inchoo_order_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
                'city'       => 'city',
                'country_id' => 'country_id'
            ))
            ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
                'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
            ))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'fullname',
                'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
                array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'products',
                '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                    FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                    WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                        AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
                array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
            )
        ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('inchoo_orders');
        $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

        $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Order #'),
            'index'  => 'increment_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('purchased_on', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Purchased On'),
            'type'   => 'datetime',
            'index'  => 'created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('products', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Products Purchased'),
            'index'        => 'products',
            'filter_index' => '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('fullname', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Name'),
            'index'        => 'fullname',
            'filter_index' => 'CONCAT(customer_firstname, \' \', customer_lastname)'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('city', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('City'),
            'index'  => 'city'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('country', array(
            'header'   => $helper->__('Country'),
            'index'    => 'country_id',
            'renderer' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_country'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Customer Group'),
            'index'  => 'customer_group_code'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header'        => $helper->__('Grand Total'),
            'index'         => 'grand_total',
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currency
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
            'index'  => 'shipping_description'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_status', array(
            'header'  => $helper->__('Status'),
            'index'   => 'status',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed it as said, nothing is appearing

Comment: See the tutorial too that link in the answer

Comment: Any other tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I found that this tutorial : [Part 1](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/)

And this tutorial: [Part 2](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part2-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/)

Could help solve your problem. I followed them when starting to study magendo admin panel and I had no problems. with it. The first part shows how to set up a grid and the second part shows advanced topics in it like filters, ajax form, csv/xml export and so on.

F